# Getter and Setter conventions in Go

Tags: go, constructor, getter-setter

**Case A** Not following the Getter & Setter convention

human/human.go

```
package human

type Human interface {
    GetName() string
    SetName(name string)
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func (p Person) GetName() string {
    return p.Name
}

func (p *Person) SetName(name string) {
    p.Name = name
}
```

main/main.go

```
package main

func main() {
    john := Person{Name:"john"} // Uppercase Fields are visible
    fmt.Println(john)
}
```

---

**Case B** Following getter and setter convention

```
package human

type Human interface {
    Name() string
    SetName(name string)
}

type Person struct {
    name string
}

func (p Person) Name() string {
    return p.name
}

func (p *Person) SetName(name string) {
    p.name = name
}
```

main/main.go

```
package main

func main() {
    john := Person(name: "John") // lowercase name is not visible outside the package
}
```

The problem with following convention is that I can't instantiate the struct while providing its field names. I'd like to use the convention but I am stuck with the private access.

Comment: Ask yourself: What is the benefit of a private name? What is the benefit from setters and getters. Then decide.

Comment: ok, good analogy, what would say if you ask the same to yourself

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When instantiating a structure (or object, in object oriented languages), you should not specify the value of private fields anyway. It can make sense, however, to provide data that may end up in private fields, or be treated in a completely different manner. In this case, OOP warrants the use of a constructor, and the Go convention is a to provide a fuction called New[YourStructure].

```
func NewPerson(name string) Person {
    return Person{name: name}
}
```

In this trivial example, the name is simply copied to the private field, but in a more complex example, other operations could take place (e.g. checking that the name is valid, or looking up the name and taking action depending on the result…).

Comment: Zoyd, thanks for the answer. I understood your New[YourStructure] approach, however, is this convention official, i noticed it around on other sites but not sure if it's official? are they using it anywhere at https://github.com/golang ?

Comment: I don’t know about "official", but it is mentioned in Effective Go (https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals) and used all over the place in the standard packages. Open any package in https://golang.org/pkg/ and look for New, you’ll find functions called NewThing in many of them.

Comment: I've no problem in using it and I'll accept your answer, but for the sake of argument I'm trying to get the reason behind on why go founders did things in a certain way and there's always a deep meaning behind, founders could have provided constructors but they didn't, meaning they don't want us to use constructors.

Comment: Then, what you are looking for is probably the sections of the FAQ about (non)-object orientation: https://golang.org/doc/faq#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language

Comment: thanks, i found something about New https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals