# Copying or passing the pointer

Tags: pointers, go, getter-setter

I've seen recommendations to use the following in getters and setters, i.e. pass a pointer when you are setting the value in order to change the original data, but it's not required when getting the value.

In the case of a getter, without a pointer, the value is copied. My question is, isn't it inefficient to copy the object to get value out of it, could we not use a pointer as well?

```
type Foo struct {
     Body string
}

func (foo Foo) GetBody() interface{} {
    return foo.Body
}

func (foo * Foo) SetBody(body string) {
    foo.Body = body
}
```

Comment: so I guess it's better to use pointer types all across both for getting and setting in order to be efficient and consistent, do you agree?

Comment: Accessing the non-pointer value, thereby creating a copy, makes it safe for concurrent access. E.g. channels.

Comment: Also, FYI, Golang convention is to NOT prefix getters with Get. Just call it `Foo.Body()` with `Foo.SetBody()`.  Setup your go environment with metalinter which will point you to better conventions.

Comment: @eduncan911 ok, so is this a deep copy? let's say foo has an array field, will that be copied too?

Comment: @eduncan911 regarding convention I agree but here's the dilemma, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739877/getter-and-setter-conventions-in-go-lang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you see a recommendation to use a non-pointer receiver for getters ? I don’t think this is done in the official packages; e.g., the [zip package](https://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/) definitely uses pointer receivers for both getters and setters.

```
func (h *FileHeader) ModTime() time.Time
func (h *FileHeader) Mode() (mode os.FileMode)
func (h *FileHeader) SetModTime(t time.Time)
func (h *FileHeader) SetMode(mode os.FileMode)
```

See also :

- [Should I define methods on values or pointers?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers)
- [How to select a receiver type](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-type)

Comment: I can't remember, somewhere non official but thanks for posting this, now I can use it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the [Go Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://golang.org/doc/faq)?

> [Should I define methods on values or pointers?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers)
>
> ```
> func (s *MyStruct) pointerMethod() { } // method on pointer
> func (s MyStruct)  valueMethod()   { } // method on value
> ```
>
> For programmers unaccustomed to pointers, the distinction between
>   these two examples can be confusing, but the situation is actually
>   very simple. When defining a method on a type, the receiver (s in the
>   above examples) behaves exactly as if it were an argument to the
>   method. Whether to define the receiver as a value or as a pointer is
>   the same question, then, as whether a function argument should be a
>   value or a pointer. There are several considerations.
>
> First, and most important, does the method need to modify the
>   receiver? If it does, the receiver must be a pointer. (Slices and maps
>   act as references, so their story is a little more subtle, but for
>   instance to change the length of a slice in a method the receiver must
>   still be a pointer.) In the examples above, if pointerMethod modifies
>   the fields of s, the caller will see those changes, but valueMethod is
>   called with a copy of the caller's argument (that's the definition of
>   passing a value), so changes it makes will be invisible to the caller.
>
> By the way, pointer receivers are identical to the situation in Java,
>   although in Java the pointers are hidden under the covers; it's Go's
>   value receivers that are unusual.
>
> Second is the consideration of efficiency. If the receiver is large, a
>   big struct for instance, it will be much cheaper to use a pointer
>   receiver.
>
> Next is consistency. If some of the methods of the type must have
>   pointer receivers, the rest should too, so the method set is
>   consistent regardless of how the type is used. See the section on
>   method sets for details.
>
> For types such as basic types, slices, and small structs, a value
>   receiver is very cheap so unless the semantics of the method requires
>   a pointer, a value receiver is efficient and clear.

Answer (score 0):

When working with struct (like the above example), use pointers whenever as possible. I don't see anything wrong passing a struct as a pointer especially when you're not modifying its value. There's cases when u don't want to do mutation on your struct so to make sure you're not modifying anything, you're not gonna pass it as a value, but when performing read only it's more prefered to use pointers in this case ;)